# Can I configure my iPhone to play audio files through ear speaker instead of the bottom speaker?

Tags: iphone, audio, quicktime, speakers

My company utilizes a voicemail system which sends audio files as email attachments. These audio files playback via QuickTime in iOS which pushes the audio out via the phone's speaker. Which is great for a Mumford and Sons song, not so great for voicemail. I can hook up headphones for private listening, but when I am without headphones wanted to use the phone's ear speaker instead.

Using an iPhone 5 and iOS 6 is it possible to play audio files played back via QuickTime with the ear speaker? If not via QuickTime is there an app for that?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't.

And as far as I can tell (searching the App Store) there are no apps that can help you. Even if there was one you wouldn't be able to open the audio file in Mail without using QuickTime, and that will always lead to the audio file playing through speaker.

Best you can do is have a pair of headphones with you and hope something changes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically possible, the Google Voice for iPhone app does this when you listen to voicemails

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-voice/id318698524?mt=8

Comment: Agreed it's possible for an app, but there is no configuration that makes it possible for audio files attached to an email message.

Answer (score 0):

1. Settings > Accessibility > Audio/Visual
2. Turn "Mono Audio" on
3. Slide balance all the way to R

Note of course it's somewhat annoying to have to turn this off / on as needed, but better than nothing. Wonder if there's a way to configure a Siri shortcut or something.

Comment: This answer assumes you hold the phone in landscape orientation, with the "top" of the phone, the end with the notch to the right, and (for iPhone 7 or 8) the home button to the left.   When I follow the steps in user Shim's answer, but re-orient my iPhone with top to the left, the sound comes out through the bottom speaker.

Comment: My assumption was to hold the phone in the portrait orientation as you would if you were holding it to your ear. If you need to hold it in a different orientation simply slide the balance to the other side.