# Play sound through earpiece speaker iphone

Tags: iphone, audio

How can i make my iPhone 7 play all sound through the earpiece?

I want to listen to music privately without headphones thought this would be an easy way to do it, pointing bottom of phone low-volume to head is awkward and doesn't work v well.

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible as the earpiece speaker is only for phone calls. Your choice is the main speaker or a headset.

From [this discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2636299)

> As far as I know this is not an option.
>
> The earpiece receiver is for phone calls, it's not a "private speaker". Your choices are the iPhones main speaker or a headset.

You can request Apple to add this functionality [here.](https://www.apple.com/feedback/)

Comment: How about as an app developer? can i send audio through the earpiece?

Comment: @theonlygusti i dont think so

Comment: [Might be useful](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/385250/77639)  — also [check out this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424446/avaudiosession-playing-audio-through-earpiece-speaker) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31692577/1032372)